# Как в календаре перейти по ссылке при клике на дату?

Tags: javascript

Есть код календаря на чистом js. При клике на активную дату всплывает попап с ссылкой на страницу. А нужно чтобы при клике на дату был сразу переход по ссылке. Перерыл все что мог, теперь у вас прошу помощи!

В опциях календаря есть опция EventClick, подозреваю что в ней надо что-то прописать, но все мои фантазии ни к чему не привели. Google тоже не помог.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

```js
/*
          Author: Jack Ducasse;
          Version: 0.1.0;
          (◠‿◠✿)
        */
var Calendar = function(model, options, date) {
  // Default Values
  this.Options = {
    Color: '',
    LinkColor: '',
    NavShow: true,
    NavVertical: false,
    NavLocation: '',
    DateTimeShow: true,
    DateTimeFormat: 'mmm, yyyy',
    DatetimeLocation: '',
    EventClick: '',
    EventTargetWholeDay: false,
    DisabledDays: [],
    ModelChange: model
  };
  // Overwriting default values
  for (var key in options) {
    this.Options[key] = typeof options[key] == 'string' ? options[key].toLowerCase() : options[key];
  }

  model ? this.Model = model : this.Model = {};
  this.Today = new Date();

  this.Selected = this.Today
  this.Today.Month = this.Today.getMonth();
  this.Today.Year = this.Today.getFullYear();
  if (date) {
    this.Selected = date
  }
  this.Selected.Month = this.Selected.getMonth();
  this.Selected.Year = this.Selected.getFullYear();

  this.Selected.Days = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month + 1), 0).getDate();
  this.Selected.FirstDay = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month), 1).getDay();
  this.Selected.LastDay = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month + 1), 0).getDay();

  this.Prev = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month - 1), 1);
  if (this.Selected.Month == 0) {
    this.Prev = new Date(this.Selected.Year - 1, 11, 1);
  }
  this.Prev.Days = new Date(this.Prev.getFullYear(), (this.Prev.getMonth() + 1), 0).getDate();
};

function createCalendar(calendar, element, adjuster) {
  if (typeof adjuster !== 'undefined') {
    var newDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month + adjuster, 1);
    calendar = new Calendar(calendar.Model, calendar.Options, newDate);
    element.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    for (var key in calendar.Options) {
      typeof calendar.Options[key] != 'function' && typeof calendar.Options[key] != 'object' && calendar.Options[key] ? element.className += " " + key + "-" + calendar.Options[key] : 0;
    }
  }
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  function AddSidebar() {
    var sidebar = document.createElement('div');
    sidebar.className += 'cld-sidebar';

    var monthList = document.createElement('ul');
    monthList.className += 'cld-monthList';

    for (var i = 0; i < months.length - 3; i++) {
      var x = document.createElement('li');
      x.className += 'cld-month';
      var n = i - (4 - calendar.Selected.Month);
      // Account for overflowing month values
      if (n < 0) {
        n += 12;
      } else if (n > 11) {
        n -= 12;
      }
      // Add Appropriate Class
      if (i == 0) {
        x.className += ' cld-rwd cld-nav';
        x.addEventListener('click', function() {
          typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
          createCalendar(calendar, element, -1);
        });
        x.innerHTML += '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 100 75" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"><polyline points="0,75 100,75 50,0"></polyline></svg>';
      } else if (i == months.length - 4) {
        x.className += ' cld-fwd cld-nav';
        x.addEventListener('click', function() {
          typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
          createCalendar(calendar, element, 1);
        });
        x.innerHTML += '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 100 75" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"><polyline points="0,0 100,0 50,75"></polyline></svg>';
      } else {
        if (i < 4) {
          x.className += ' cld-pre';
        } else if (i > 4) {
          x.className += ' cld-post';
        } else {
          x.className += ' cld-curr';
        }

        //prevent losing var adj value (for whatever reason that is happening)
        (function() {
          var adj = (i - 4);
          //x.addEventListener('click', function(){createCalendar(calendar, element, adj);console.log('kk', adj);} );
          x.addEventListener('click', function() {
            typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
            createCalendar(calendar, element, adj);
          });
          x.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:' + (1 - Math.abs(adj) / 4));
          x.innerHTML += months[n].substr(0, 3);
        }()); // immediate invocation

        if (n == 0) {
          var y = document.createElement('li');
          y.className += 'cld-year';
          if (i < 5) {
            y.innerHTML += calendar.Selected.Year;
          } else {
            y.innerHTML += calendar.Selected.Year + 1;
          }
          monthList.appendChild(y);
        }
      }
      monthList.appendChild(x);
    }
    sidebar.appendChild(monthList);
    if (calendar.Options.NavLocation) {
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.NavLocation).innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.NavLocation).appendChild(sidebar);
    } else {
      element.appendChild(sidebar);
    }
  }

  var mainSection = document.createElement('div');
  mainSection.className += "cld-main";

  function AddDateTime() {
    var datetime = document.createElement('div');
    datetime.className += "cld-datetime";
    if (calendar.Options.NavShow && !calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
      var rwd = document.createElement('div');
      rwd.className += " cld-rwd cld-nav";
      rwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
        createCalendar(calendar, element, -1);
      });
      rwd.innerHTML = '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 75 100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"><polyline points="0,50 75,0 75,100"></polyline></svg>';
      datetime.appendChild(rwd);
    }
    var today = document.createElement('div');
    today.className += ' today';
    today.innerHTML = months[calendar.Selected.Month] + ", " + calendar.Selected.Year;
    datetime.appendChild(today);
    if (calendar.Options.NavShow && !calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
      var fwd = document.createElement('div');
      fwd.className += " cld-fwd cld-nav";
      fwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
        createCalendar(calendar, element, 1);
      });
      fwd.innerHTML = '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 75 100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"><polyline points="0,0 75,50 0,100"></polyline></svg>';
      datetime.appendChild(fwd);
    }
    if (calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation) {
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation).innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation).appendChild(datetime);
    } else {
      mainSection.appendChild(datetime);
    }
  }

  function AddLabels() {
    var labels = document.createElement('ul');
    labels.className = 'cld-labels';
    var labelsList = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    for (var i = 0; i < labelsList.length; i++) {
      var label = document.createElement('li');
      label.className += "cld-label";
      label.innerHTML = labelsList[i];
      labels.appendChild(label);
    }
    mainSection.appendChild(labels);
  }

  function AddDays() {
    // Create Number Element
    function DayNumber(n) {
      var number = document.createElement('p');
      number.className += "cld-number";
      number.innerHTML += n;
      return number;
    }
    var days = document.createElement('ul');
    days.className += "cld-days";
    // Previous Month's Days
    for (var i = 0; i < (calendar.Selected.FirstDay); i++) {
      var day = document.createElement('li');
      day.className += "cld-day prevMonth";
      //Disabled Days
      var d = i % 7;
      for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
        if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
          day.className += " disableDay";
        }
      }

      var number = DayNumber((calendar.Prev.Days - calendar.Selected.FirstDay) + (i + 1));
      day.appendChild(number);

      days.appendChild(day);
    }
    // Current Month's Days
    for (var i = 0; i < calendar.Selected.Days; i++) {
      var day = document.createElement('li');
      day.className += "cld-day currMonth";
      //Disabled Days
      var d = (i + calendar.Selected.FirstDay) % 7;
      for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
        if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
          day.className += " disableDay";
        }
      }
      var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
      // Check Date against Event Dates
      for (var n = 0; n < calendar.Model.length; n++) {
        var evDate = calendar.Model[n].Date;
        var toDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month, (i + 1));
        if (evDate.getTime() == toDate.getTime()) {
          number.className += " eventday";
          var title = document.createElement('span');
          title.className += "cld-title";
          if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link == 'function' || calendar.Options.EventClick) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute('href', '#');
            a.innerHTML += calendar.Model[n].Title;
            if (calendar.Options.EventClick) {
              var z = calendar.Model[n].Link;
              if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link != 'string') {
                a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
                if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                  day.className += " clickable";
                  day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
                }
              } else {
                a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
                if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                  day.className += " clickable";
                  day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
                }
              }
            } else {
              a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
              if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                day.className += " clickable";
                day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
              }
            }
            title.appendChild(a);
          } else {
            title.innerHTML += '<a href="' + calendar.Model[n].Link + '">' + calendar.Model[n].Title + '</a>';
          }
          number.appendChild(title);
        }
      }
      day.appendChild(number);
      // If Today..
      if ((i + 1) == calendar.Today.getDate() && calendar.Selected.Month == calendar.Today.Month && calendar.Selected.Year == calendar.Today.Year) {
        day.className += " today";
      }
      days.appendChild(day);
    }
    // Next Month's Days
    // Always same amount of days in calander
    var extraDays = 13;
    if (days.children.length > 35) {
      extraDays = 6;
    } else if (days.children.length < 29) {
      extraDays = 20;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < (extraDays - calendar.Selected.LastDay); i++) {
      var day = document.createElement('li');
      day.className += "cld-day nextMonth";
      //Disabled Days
      var d = (i + calendar.Selected.LastDay + 1) % 7;
      for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
        if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
          day.className += " disableDay";
        }
      }

      var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
      day.appendChild(number);

      days.appendChild(day);
    }
    mainSection.appendChild(days);
  }
  if (calendar.Options.Color) {
    mainSection.innerHTML += '<style>.cld-main{color:' + calendar.Options.Color + ';}</style>';
  }
  if (calendar.Options.LinkColor) {
    mainSection.innerHTML += '<style>.cld-title a{color:' + calendar.Options.LinkColor + ';}</style>';
  }
  element.appendChild(mainSection);

  if (calendar.Options.NavShow && calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
    AddSidebar();
  }
  if (calendar.Options.DateTimeShow) {
    AddDateTime();
  }
  AddLabels();
  AddDays();
}

function caleandar(el, data, settings) {
  var obj = new Calendar(data, settings);
  createCalendar(obj, el);
} 
  var events = [{
      'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 17),
      'Title': 'Doctor appointment at 3:25pm.'
    },
    {
      'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 18),
      'Title': 'New Garfield movie comes out!',
      'Link': 'https://garfield.com'
    },
    {
      'Date': new Date(2020, 1, 27),
      'Title': '25 year anniversary',
      'Link': 'http://google.com/'
    },
  ];

var settings = {
  Color: 'blue',
  LinkColor: 'red',
  EventClick: ''
};

var element = document.getElementById('caleandar');
caleandar(element, events, settings);
```

```css
.cld-main {
  width: 330px;
}

.cld-main a {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cld-datetime {
  position: relative;
  width: 66%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cld-datetime .today {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.cld-nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.cld-nav:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cld-nav:hover svg {
  fill: #666;
}

.cld-rwd {
  float: left;
}

.cld-fwd {
  float: right;
}

.cld-nav svg:hover {}

.cld-labels,
.cld-days {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.cld-label,
.cld-day {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14.28%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cld-day.today .cld-number {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}

.cld-day.disableDay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.cld-day.nextMonth,
.cld-day.prevMonth {
  opacity: 0.33;
}

.cld-number {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.cld-title {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.cld-number:hover .cld-title {
  display: block;
}

.cld-title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -7.5px;
  left: 7.5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7.5px solid #ccc;
}

.cld-number.eventday {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.cld-number.eventday:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eee;
}

.today .cld-number.eventday:hover {
  background: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="caleandar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А что за календарь то? Думаете, в мире существует всего одна реализация календаря на js?

Comment: Приведите код в порядок, т.к. при нажатии на кнопку "Выполнить код" возникает ошибка. Если ты хотите получать ответы на ваши вопросы, то необходимо загружать исходный код в читаемом, удобном и самое главное - рабочем (в том плане, что он запускается и выдает такой же результат, что и у Вас на пк) виде.

Comment: Поправил ваш код...в следующий раз, вставляйте работающий. 99% это копипаста откуда-то. Вы думаете, вам помогут дописать чей-то календарь, и вы при этом ничего не сделаете...пардон, 100% `Author: Jack Ducasse`

Comment: 1) Находите ваши даты, по которым нужно ссылки прописать по `js` (`class="eventdata"`).  2) Я б вместо `div` написал `a`, чтобы не прариться.

Comment: Спасибо! Тут исправить не смог, уже создал дубликат вопроса с работающим примером. "Находите ваши даты, по которым нужно ссылки прописать по js (class="eventdata")" - не понял, как практически это реализовать в данном случае. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Максим `document.querySelectorAll(".eventdata")` найдет все элементы с классом `eventdata`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант находим в коде где у нас создается подсказки с евентом и заменяем создание span с подсказакой на простую линку

```js
/*
          Author: Jack Ducasse;
          Version: 0.1.0;
          (◠‿◠✿)
        */
var Calendar = function(model, options, date) {
  // Default Values
  this.Options = {
    Color: '',
    LinkColor: '',
    NavShow: true,
    NavVertical: false,
    NavLocation: '',
    DateTimeShow: true,
    DateTimeFormat: 'mmm, yyyy',
    DatetimeLocation: '',
    EventClick: '',
    EventTargetWholeDay: false,
    DisabledDays: [],
    ModelChange: model
  };
  // Overwriting default values
  for (var key in options) {
    this.Options[key] = typeof options[key] == 'string' ? options[key].toLowerCase() : options[key];
  }

  model ? this.Model = model : this.Model = {};
  this.Today = new Date();

  this.Selected = this.Today
  this.Today.Month = this.Today.getMonth();
  this.Today.Year = this.Today.getFullYear();
  if (date) {
    this.Selected = date
  }
  this.Selected.Month = this.Selected.getMonth();
  this.Selected.Year = this.Selected.getFullYear();

  this.Selected.Days = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month + 1), 0).getDate();
  this.Selected.FirstDay = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month), 1).getDay();
  this.Selected.LastDay = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month + 1), 0).getDay();

  this.Prev = new Date(this.Selected.Year, (this.Selected.Month - 1), 1);
  if (this.Selected.Month == 0) {
    this.Prev = new Date(this.Selected.Year - 1, 11, 1);
  }
  this.Prev.Days = new Date(this.Prev.getFullYear(), (this.Prev.getMonth() + 1), 0).getDate();
};

function createCalendar(calendar, element, adjuster) {
  if (typeof adjuster !== 'undefined') {
    var newDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month + adjuster, 1);
    calendar = new Calendar(calendar.Model, calendar.Options, newDate);
    element.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    for (var key in calendar.Options) {
      typeof calendar.Options[key] != 'function' && typeof calendar.Options[key] != 'object' && calendar.Options[key] ? element.className += " " + key + "-" + calendar.Options[key] : 0;
    }
  }
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  function AddSidebar() {
    var sidebar = document.createElement('div');
    sidebar.className += 'cld-sidebar';

    var monthList = document.createElement('ul');
    monthList.className += 'cld-monthList';

    for (var i = 0; i < months.length - 3; i++) {
      var x = document.createElement('li');
      x.className += 'cld-month';
      var n = i - (4 - calendar.Selected.Month);
      // Account for overflowing month values
      if (n < 0) {
        n += 12;
      } else if (n > 11) {
        n -= 12;
      }
      // Add Appropriate Class
      if (i == 0) {
        x.className += ' cld-rwd cld-nav';
        x.addEventListener('click', function() {
          typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
          createCalendar(calendar, element, -1);
        });
        x.innerHTML += '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 100 75" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"><polyline points="0,75 100,75 50,0"></polyline></svg>';
      } else if (i == months.length - 4) {
        x.className += ' cld-fwd cld-nav';
        x.addEventListener('click', function() {
          typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
          createCalendar(calendar, element, 1);
        });
        x.innerHTML += '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 100 75" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"><polyline points="0,0 100,0 50,75"></polyline></svg>';
      } else {
        if (i < 4) {
          x.className += ' cld-pre';
        } else if (i > 4) {
          x.className += ' cld-post';
        } else {
          x.className += ' cld-curr';
        }

        //prevent losing var adj value (for whatever reason that is happening)
        (function() {
          var adj = (i - 4);
          //x.addEventListener('click', function(){createCalendar(calendar, element, adj);console.log('kk', adj);} );
          x.addEventListener('click', function() {
            typeof calendar.Options.ModelChange == 'function' ? calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange() : calendar.Model = calendar.Options.ModelChange;
            createCalendar(calendar, element, adj);
          });
          x.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:' + (1 - Math.abs(adj) / 4));
          x.innerHTML += months[n].substr(0, 3);
        }()); // immediate invocation

        if (n == 0) {
          var y = document.createElement('li');
          y.className += 'cld-year';
          if (i < 5) {
            y.innerHTML += calendar.Selected.Year;
          } else {
            y.innerHTML += calendar.Selected.Year + 1;
          }
          monthList.appendChild(y);
        }
      }
      monthList.appendChild(x);
    }
    sidebar.appendChild(monthList);
    if (calendar.Options.NavLocation) {
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.NavLocation).innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.NavLocation).appendChild(sidebar);
    } else {
      element.appendChild(sidebar);
    }
  }

  var mainSection = document.createElement('div');
  mainSection.className += "cld-main";

  function AddDateTime() {
    var datetime = document.createElement('div');
    datetime.className += "cld-datetime";
    if (calendar.Options.NavShow && !calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
      var rwd = document.createElement('div');
      rwd.className += " cld-rwd cld-nav";
      rwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
        createCalendar(calendar, element, -1);
      });
      rwd.innerHTML = '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 75 100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"><polyline points="0,50 75,0 75,100"></polyline></svg>';
      datetime.appendChild(rwd);
    }
    var today = document.createElement('div');
    today.className += ' today';
    today.innerHTML = months[calendar.Selected.Month] + ", " + calendar.Selected.Year;
    datetime.appendChild(today);
    if (calendar.Options.NavShow && !calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
      var fwd = document.createElement('div');
      fwd.className += " cld-fwd cld-nav";
      fwd.addEventListener('click', function() {
        createCalendar(calendar, element, 1);
      });
      fwd.innerHTML = '<svg height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 75 100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"><polyline points="0,0 75,50 0,100"></polyline></svg>';
      datetime.appendChild(fwd);
    }
    if (calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation) {
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation).innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById(calendar.Options.DatetimeLocation).appendChild(datetime);
    } else {
      mainSection.appendChild(datetime);
    }
  }

  function AddLabels() {
    var labels = document.createElement('ul');
    labels.className = 'cld-labels';
    var labelsList = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    for (var i = 0; i < labelsList.length; i++) {
      var label = document.createElement('li');
      label.className += "cld-label";
      label.innerHTML = labelsList[i];
      labels.appendChild(label);
    }
    mainSection.appendChild(labels);
  }

  function AddDays() {
    // Create Number Element
    function DayNumber(n) {
      var number = document.createElement('p');
      number.className += "cld-number";
      number.innerHTML += n;
      return number;
    }
    var days = document.createElement('ul');
    days.className += "cld-days";
    // Previous Month's Days
    for (var i = 0; i < (calendar.Selected.FirstDay); i++) {
      var day = document.createElement('li');
      day.className += "cld-day prevMonth";
      //Disabled Days
      var d = i % 7;
      for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
        if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
          day.className += " disableDay";
        }
      }

      var number = DayNumber((calendar.Prev.Days - calendar.Selected.FirstDay) + (i + 1));
      day.appendChild(number);

      days.appendChild(day);
    }
    // Current Month's Days
    for (var i = 0; i < calendar.Selected.Days; i++) {
      var day = document.createElement('li');
      day.className += "cld-day currMonth";
      //Disabled Days
      var d = (i + calendar.Selected.FirstDay) % 7;
      for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
        if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
          day.className += " disableDay";
        }
      }
      var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
      // Check Date against Event Dates
      for (var n = 0; n < calendar.Model.length; n++) {
        var evDate = calendar.Model[n].Date;
        var toDate = new Date(calendar.Selected.Year, calendar.Selected.Month, (i + 1));
        if (evDate.getTime() == toDate.getTime()) {
          number.className += " eventday";
          //Здесь и ниже убираем создание подсказки и вместо нее создаем ссылку внутри даты
          //   var link = document.createElement('a');
          //   console.log(calendar.Model[n].Link)
          //   link.setAttribute('href', calendar.Model[n].Link);
          //   number.appendChild(link);
          //   var title = document.createElement('span');
          //   title.className += "cld-title";
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link == 'function' || calendar.Options.EventClick) {
            //var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute('href', '#');
            //a.innerHTML += calendar.Model[n].Title;
            if (calendar.Options.EventClick) {
              var z = calendar.Model[n].Link;
              if (typeof calendar.Model[n].Link != 'string') {
                a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
                if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                  day.className += " clickable";
                  day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind.apply(calendar.Options.EventClick, [null].concat(z)));
                }
              } else {
                a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
                if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                  day.className += " clickable";
                  day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Options.EventClick.bind(null, z));
                }
              }
            } else {
              a.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
              if (calendar.Options.EventTargetWholeDay) {
                day.className += " clickable";
                day.addEventListener('click', calendar.Model[n].Link);
              }
            }
            number.appendChild(a);
          } else {
            number.appendChild(a);
            a.setAttribute('href', calendar.Model[n].Link)
            //title.innerHTML += '<a href="' + calendar.Model[n].Link + '">' + calendar.Model[n].Title + '</a>';
          }
          //number.appendChild(title);
        }
      }
      day.appendChild(number);
      // If Today..
      if ((i + 1) == calendar.Today.getDate() && calendar.Selected.Month == calendar.Today.Month && calendar.Selected.Year == calendar.Today.Year) {
        day.className += " today";
      }
      days.appendChild(day);
    }
    // Next Month's Days
    // Always same amount of days in calander
    var extraDays = 13;
    if (days.children.length > 35) {
      extraDays = 6;
    } else if (days.children.length < 29) {
      extraDays = 20;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < (extraDays - calendar.Selected.LastDay); i++) {
      var day = document.createElement('li');
      day.className += "cld-day nextMonth";
      //Disabled Days
      var d = (i + calendar.Selected.LastDay + 1) % 7;
      for (var q = 0; q < calendar.Options.DisabledDays.length; q++) {
        if (d == calendar.Options.DisabledDays[q]) {
          day.className += " disableDay";
        }
      }

      var number = DayNumber(i + 1);
      day.appendChild(number);

      days.appendChild(day);
    }
    mainSection.appendChild(days);
  }
  if (calendar.Options.Color) {
    mainSection.innerHTML += '<style>.cld-main{color:' + calendar.Options.Color + ';}</style>';
  }
  if (calendar.Options.LinkColor) {
    mainSection.innerHTML += '<style>.cld-title a{color:' + calendar.Options.LinkColor + ';}</style>';
  }
  element.appendChild(mainSection);

  if (calendar.Options.NavShow && calendar.Options.NavVertical) {
    AddSidebar();
  }
  if (calendar.Options.DateTimeShow) {
    AddDateTime();
  }
  AddLabels();
  AddDays();
}

function caleandar(el, data, settings) {
  var obj = new Calendar(data, settings);
  createCalendar(obj, el);
}
var events = [{
    'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 17),
    'Title': 'Doctor appointment at 3:25pm.',
    'Link': 'https://test.com'
  },
  {
    'Date': new Date(2020, 0, 18),
    'Title': 'New Garfield movie comes out!',
    'Link': 'https://garfield.com'
  },
  {
    'Date': new Date(2020, 1, 27),
    'Title': '25 year anniversary',
    'Link': 'http://google.com/'
  },
];

var settings = {
  Color: 'blue',
  LinkColor: 'red',
  EventClick: ''
};

var element = document.getElementById('caleandar');
caleandar(element, events, settings);
```

```css
.cld-main {
  width: 330px;
}

.cld-main a {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cld-datetime {
  position: relative;
  width: 66%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cld-datetime .today {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.cld-nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.cld-nav:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cld-nav:hover svg {
  fill: #666;
}

.cld-rwd {
  float: left;
}

.cld-fwd {
  float: right;
}

.cld-nav svg:hover {}

.cld-labels,
.cld-days {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.cld-label,
.cld-day {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14.28%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cld-day.today .cld-number {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}

.cld-day.disableDay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.cld-day.nextMonth,
.cld-day.prevMonth {
  opacity: 0.33;
}

.cld-number {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.cld-title {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.cld-number:hover .cld-title {
  display: block;
}

.cld-title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -7.5px;
  left: 7.5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7.5px solid #ccc;
}

.cld-number.eventday {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.cld-number.eventday a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.cld-number.eventday:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eee;
}

.today .cld-number.eventday:hover {
  background: #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="caleandar"></div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все работает! И еще одна просьба - ваш js-код отдельно без css не дает результата, но я не смог найти в этом css стиля, который на это влияет. Подскажите, где он?)

Comment: Там добавлены стили для новой ссылки ".cld-number.eventday a"

Comment: Огромное спасибо!